# Change TreeView path from another thread C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How do you update a treeview from a different thread? My treeview acts like explorer and enables the user to select a different parent folder. When I try and change the parent from a different UI nothing happens, guessing because its using a different thread.
I've read multiple examples explaining the use of 'Invoke' and delegates but cannot get it working.

Comment: All of your UIs are running in the application's main thread unless you've created new threads on your own.

Comment: The controls are hosted in a usercontrol which is used to create tool palette in AutoCAD. The tool palette has it's own ContextMenu which is where I'm trying to add Methods to change the Treeview library etc... If I simply call treeView.Nodes.Clear(); from the toolPalette nothing happens, whereas this works fine within the usercontrol. This led me to believe it was a thread issue

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this. The execution context must be marshaled to the UI thread.

```
treeView.HandleCreated += (s, a) => {
     treeView.Invoke(new Action(() => treeView.Nodes.Clear()));
};
```

Also, try this from the context menu select event using the Invoke method of the calling control.

```
Invoke(new Action(() => treeView.Nodes.Clear()));
```

Comment: This returned the following error: Invoke or BeginInvoke cannot be called on a control until the window handle has been created

Comment: see my update. There is no real reason to call Clear() on a treeview as it's being created because it's already empty. I'm beginning to think you're control isn't being created when you think it is.

Comment: Sorry I was just using 'Clear();' as an example

Comment: Tried the revised code but nothing happens this time. The treeview is visible on the screen before attempting to clear from the context menu

Comment: I can read properties from the treeView via the contextmenu, no problem? Really flummoxed with this one